# Unable to remove red underlines for XML import object in SQL Server Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, xquery, openrowset

I am importing an XML file into SQL Server 2019 using SSMS from a Windows 10 desktop. The script works but there are red underlines showing in the editor that make the code look like something is wrong.

I have tried closing SSMS and reopening but they are still there. I tried refreshing the intellisense from the main menu but still they are there.

This is the code:

[image]

Below is the code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.TechCourses;
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION

CREATE TABLE dbo.TechCourses
(
    CourseName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    CourseCode varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    StartDate datetime NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    StudentID int NOT NULL,
    Membership varchar(20) NOT NULL
)
GO

ALTER TABLE TechCourses
ADD CONSTRAINT TechCourses_PK PRIMARY KEY (StudentID, CourseName);
GO

COMMIT

INSERT INTO dbo.TechCourses (CourseName, CourseCode, StartDate, FirstName, LastName, StudentID, Membership)
    SELECT 
        XMLFromFile.Applicant.query('CourseName').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
        XMLFromFile.Applicant.query('CourseCode').value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)'),
        XMLFromFile.Applicant.query('StartDate').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
        XMLFromFile.Applicant.query('FirstName').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
        XMLFromFile.Applicant.query('LastName').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
        XMLFromFile.Applicant.query('StudentID').value('.', 'VARCHAR(16)'),
        XMLFromFile.Applicant.query('Membership').value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)')
    FROM 
        (SELECT CAST(XMLFromFile AS xml)
         FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\FilesForTesting\XmlLoadTest2.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(XMLFromFile)) AS T(XMLFromFile)
    CROSS APPLY 
        XMLFromFile.nodes('Root/Applicants/Applicant') AS XMLFromFile (Applicant);
```

The `XMLFromFile` object recognizes the `Applicant` sub object when I type a period after the object name. When I move the cursor under the red underline items the following message appears:

> "Applicant" is not a valid function, property, or field.

The XML being imported is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
      <Applicants>
        <Applicant>
          <CourseName>Data Analytics 101 - Beginner"</CourseName>
          <CourseCode>DA101</CourseCode>
          <StartDate>2022-08-01 08:00:00</StartDate>
          <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
          <LastName>Stewart</LastName>
          <StudentID>301</StudentID>
          <Membership>Gold</Membership>
        </Applicant>
        <Applicant>
          <CourseName>Data Analytics 101 - Beginner"</CourseName>
          <CourseCode>DA101</CourseCode>
          <StartDate>2022-08-01 08:00:00</StartDate>
          <FirstName>Sandy</FirstName>
          <LastName>Gomez</LastName>
          <StudentID>302</StudentID>
          <Membership>Bronze</Membership>
        </Applicant>
        <Applicant>
          <CourseName>Data Analytics 101 - Beginner"</CourseName>
          <CourseCode>DA101</CourseCode>
          <StartDate>2022-08-01 08:00:00</StartDate>
          <FirstName>Cindy</FirstName>
          <LastName>Yarnov</LastName>
          <StudentID>303</StudentID>
          <Membership>Silver</Membership>
        </Applicant>
        <Applicant>
          <CourseName>Data Analytics 101 - Beginner"</CourseName>
          <CourseCode>DA101</CourseCode>
          <StartDate>2022-08-01 08:00:00</StartDate>
          <FirstName>Olek</FirstName>
          <LastName>Kovalenko</LastName>
          <StudentID>304</StudentID>
          <Membership>Gold</Membership>
        </Applicant>
        <Applicant>
          <CourseName>Data Analytics 101 - Beginner"</CourseName>
          <CourseCode>DA101</CourseCode>
          <StartDate>2022-08-01 08:00:00</StartDate>
          <FirstName>Sergio</FirstName>
          <LastName>Lopez</LastName>
          <StudentID>305</StudentID>
          <Membership>Gold</Membership>
        </Applicant>
      </Applicants>
</Root>
```

Is there something not right in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing syntactically wrong with your query, although SSMS may be getting confused due to the fact that you have a column and a derived table by the same name.

You might be able to un-confuse it by renaming one of them.

Further improvements include putting the conversion inside an `APPLY`, and using `.value` as it's supposed to be used (without unnecessary `.query`), and using correct data types.

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.TechCourses 
(
    CourseName, CourseCode, StartDate, FirstName, LastName, StudentID, Membership
)
SELECT 
   x1.Applicant.value('(CourseName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
   x1.Applicant.value('(CourseCode/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)'),
   x1.Applicant.value('(StartDate/text())[1]', 'datetime'),
   x1.Applicant.value('(FirstName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
   x1.Applicant.value('(LastName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
   x1.Applicant.value('(StudentID/text())[1]', 'int'),
   x1.Applicant.value('(Membership/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')

FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\FilesForTesting\XmlLoadTest2.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T1(BinaryData)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    CAST(T1.BinaryData AS xml)
) ) AS T2(XMLFromFile)

CROSS APPLY T2.XMLFromFile.nodes('Root/Applicants/Applicant') AS x1(Applicant);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=be4ed57286e0c4975d1305c129f7b3d1)